# D3.js Simple Line Chart on Array with Dates

Tags: d3.js

Im a D3 newbie and am having problems creating simple line chart with x data being a date.  Having problems reading in the Date variable (x) from the local array x.

Problem is partly my call of d3.time.format and returning of to the svg.line function.

```
    <title>D3 PATHS 2 tutorial </title>
     <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    </head>

<body>


    <script>

     var lineDataNew = [['2014-07-22 14:00:00',22979.57],['2014-07-22 14:15:00',22980.77],['2014-07-22 14:30:00',22981.99]];  
  var newData = [];
  var newlineData;

  for   (index = 0; index < lineDataNew.length; index++) {
      var strelement =    lineDataNew[index].toString() ;
      var arr = strelement.split(",");
       newlineData = newlineData + "{" + "x:'" + arr[0] + "', y:" + arr[1] + "}"
       newData.push(newlineData);
    if (index < arr.length) {    newlineData = newlineData + ",";   }                   
    }
            newlineData = newlineData + "]";

     var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 500)
      .attr("height",500)

    var group = canvas.append("g")
            .attr("transform","translate(100, 100)");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
         .x(function (d) {   return  d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse('2014-07-22 14:15:00'); }  )
          .x(function (d) {  return  d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse(d.x); }  )
     //     .x(function (d) {    return  d.x ; }  )
       .y(function (d) {return d.y;  } )

    group.selectAll("path")
                .data([newData])
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", line)
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", "#000")
                .attr("stroke-width", 10);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess, the lines `newlineData = newlineData + "{" + "x:'" + arr[0] + "', y:" + arr[1] + "}" newData.push(newlineData)` should add an object to the array!?  What it really does is, it adds a string. The string _newlineData_ gets longer and longer, but as it was never initialized like `var newlineData="";` it results in something like _"undefined{x:'2014-07-22 14:00:00', y:22979.57},{x:'2014-07-22 14:15:00', y:22980.77},"_

Comment: I also don't understand: the code starts with a 2 dimensional array. Why first `var strelement = originalData[index].toString();`and then `split(...)`. I'll try a few minutes to update your code.

Comment: may be you want to checkout this site https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js for examples of path lines

Comment: Code started with 2 dimensionless array because I was porting array output from jQplot and I did not think (I don't know) I could use 2 dim. array in D3. I was transforming it into a JSON object - but wasn't having any luck- then tried to build a new array with x and y attributes that I though D3 could use.  I will change my code an retry per your comments - Thanks.